# How to prevent relayd on OpenBSD from using all memory

Tags: memory, openbsd, limit, out-of-memory

I have an OpenBSD "firewall" with relayd, where relayd starts to consume all available memory to the point that the system becomes completely non responsive.  This happens when a user starts a very large file transfer (The relayd is set up as a load balancer for MinIO cluster)

Solving the relayd issue is a separate issue that needs to be addressed.

How can I limit how much memory relayd, and all its child processes, can use, to prevent it from causing the system to become hung?

Answer (score 2):

By default, `/etc/rc`-based daemons are started using the limits defined on the `daemon` section of `login.conf`:

```
daemon:\
    :ignorenologin:\
    :datasize=4096M:\
    :maxproc=infinity:\
    :openfiles-max=1024:\
    :openfiles-cur=128:\
    :stacksize-cur=8M:\
    :tc=default:
```

The `tc=default` indicates that all other settings are those defined on the `default` class, defined earlier in the file.

If you want to change the amount of memory available for `relayd`, you'll want to change the `datasize`.  The default is set at 4Gb, you'll probably want something smaller, depending on your machine.  This will, of course, limit the memory available for all other daemons, but since the problem seems to be a memory-limited machine, this is probably a good idea.

If you want to change the limits *specifically* for `relayd`, without changing other daemons, you could do something like adding a new `relayd` class to the file, with its own limits (not forgetting to add `:tc=daemon:` at the end, so that all other limits for the `daemon` class apply):

```
relayd:\
    :datasize=1024M:\
    :tc=daemon:
```

And then add the `_relayd` user to the `relayd` class:

```
# usermod -L relayd _relayd
```

If you look at the whole `/etc/login.conf` file, you'll see that this method is used to allow `vmd` to have more memory available, to let `unbound` have more `openfiles`, etc.

Comment: I se that there is a statement for "datasize=infinity" in the daemon section.  Since my server has 16 GB and I want to allow relayd to use most of it, I will create a relayd section with 14GB.  One question - is a daemon a single process, or a process and all children?  Or is it the total for all processes owned by a single user?

Comment: From the MAN page it appears the class is specified with `L`.  I found the missing information here: https://wiki.ircnow.org/index.php?n=Openbsd.Loginconf

Comment: Sorry for the typo. Corrected, thanks. I'm not 100% sure of this, but by reading the [man page for `getrlimit`](https://man.openbsd.org/getrlimit) I think that the limits are per-process _and_ its child processes.